# Passing a variable with appcelerator titanium Functions

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I have a code that i need to get an image from. I have a row that i want an image that i get from an API call. I am lost on how to get it.

This is where i get my row

```
Ti.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath(Titanium.App.Properties.getString("pageID") +'/feed',     {access_token: Token}, 'GET', function(e){
    if (e.success) {

        json = JSON.parse(e.result);
for (i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
    data = json.data[i];
    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height:'80dp',
         // backgroundImage : 'images/tablebgl.png',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        separatorColor:'transparent',
    });
row.coverid = data.from.id;     

var coverid = row.coverid;  

   Titanium.App.Properties.setString("cv", coverid);

    var imag = Ti.UI.createImageView();
row.add(imag);
require('image').get.signUpConn(data, function(scrollView){ 
imag.setImage(scrollView);
});
```

And this is my 'image.js'

```
exports.signUpConn = function(data, callback) {
    var scrollView = Ti.UI.createView({
        top : 0,
        right : -1,
        left : -1,
        backgroundColor : 'transparent',
        width : '95%',
        contentWidth : 'auto',
        contentHeight : 'auto',
        layout : 'horizontal'
    });

    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + Titanium.App.Properties.getString("cv") + "?fields=cover";
    var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    loader.onload = function(data) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var images = [];
        for (var c = 0; c < 1; c++) {
            images[c] = {
                image : data.cover.source,
                width : 300
            };

        }
        function square(i) {
            var view = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                image : images[i].image,
                width : 300,
                height : 111,
                top : 5,
            });
            return view;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            scrollView.add(square(i));
        }

    }
    callback(scrollView);
    loader.open("GET", url);
    loader.send(data);

}
```

So i guess that the error must be in the function and/or callback.

The image will be in the 'scrollView'.

I am a total mess when it comes to functions and calbacks back and forth.

this is the error i get:

```
Script Error = 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'require('image').get.signUpConn')
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You code has multiple syntax errors (the Facebook request, lots of missing brackets) but the error your reffering to is because of this:

```
require('image').get.signUpConn(data, function(scrollView){ 
    imag.setImage(scrollView); // Why do you need this here? 
});
```

It needs to be this instead, there is no need for the `get`:

```
require('image').signUpConn(data, function(scrollView){ 
    imag.setImage(scrollView);
});
```

But this is a deeper issue, your calling the `callback` too early, before the images are even loaded in `image.js`. Also, why are you creating `scrollView` (which is just a regular view) and passing it through the callback? And why do you have a for loop that only loops once?

It looks like to partially fix this, move the scrollView outside all this, pass the `images` array to the callback, and then add the images using your square function inside the callback like this:

```
require('image').signUpConn(data, function(images){ 
    for(var i = 0;i<images.length;i++) {    
        scrollView.add(square(image[i]);
    }
});
```

You will have to change some stuff around in your square function as well.

Comment: Ok..

As i said earlier i am really bad at passing this back and forth so if you pls could help me with this maybe i'd understand how it works.

Here is full code for my tableView.
http://pastie.org/5676117 

And here is my image.js
http://pastie.org/5676123 

Thanx

Comment: Refine your question to be more specific, I dont know what your asking me. Have you studied literature online about [callbacks](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) and [JavaScript in general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)?